# Migrating Angular Material to v12 does not remove old import syntax

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular12, angular-upgrade

I upgraded my Angular app to v12, and since I am using Material, I upgraded Material as well.

In the [v12 announcement article](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49) they said that Material now expose new `@use` syntax and upgrade should migrate syntax automatically. They also added [code example](https://gist.github.com/MarkTechson/6283b6a3b353f9e38964af0740e29280) of the **new VS old syntax**.

So basically `@import '~@angular/material/theming;` should be replaced with `@use '~@angular/material' as mat;`.

When I checked changes after upgrade finished successfully, I noticed that in the `styles.scss` the `@use '~@angular/material' as mat;` line were added, **BUT** `@import '~@angular/material/theming;` line was **NOT removed**. So now, I have both `@use` and `import` in my `styles.scss` file.

Should I remove `@import '~@angular/material/theming;`? As I understand, it will import the same thing twice, so it can only increase the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

As announced [here](https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched) the new `@use` is an improvement on how often scss files are imported. Basically both `@import` and `@use` work. BUT `@use` has potentially a better performance.